# Cannot convert data from cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I want to make a method that will count the number of user actions on the site. 
I have the code:

```rb
    def actions_counter
      if cookies[:"actions"] != nil
        cookies[:"actions"].to_i += 1
      else
        cookies[:"actions"] = 0
      end
    end
```

But for some reason this does not work.

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#show
undefined method `to_i=' for "1":String Did you mean? to_i to_r to_f to_s to_d to_c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your method to

```
def actions_counter
  if cookies[:actions]
    cookies[:actions] = cookies[:actions].to_i + 1
  else
    cookies[:actions] = 0
  end
end
```

The issue is that Ruby understands `cookies[:"actions"].to_i += 1` as

```
cookies[:"actions"].to_i = cookies[:"actions"].to_i + 1
        # and this ^^^^^^^^ doesn't make sense
```